# Not able to add the fill between the paths. using d3js

Tags: d3.js

i am trying to fill the background between 2 lines, but i am not getting any correct output.

and i would like to remove the `tick` line in the `y` axis as well. how to get this both?

here is my code : any one correct me please?

```
$(function(){
 var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
        var w = 300; // width
        var h = 450; // height

        var plan = 55;
        var actual = 38;
        var variation = plan - actual;

        var data = [0,plan];
        var data1 = [0,actual];

        var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2]).range([0, w]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([h, 0]);


        var line = d3.svg.line()

            .x(function(d,i) { 
                return x(i); 
            })
            .y(function(d) { 

                return y(d); 
            })


            var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
                  .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                  .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                .append("svg:g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");


            var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickSize(-w).orient("left");

            graph.append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(-0,0)")
                  .call(yAxisLeft);


                graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
            graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data1));

            //not able to fill the bg between 2 lines

             var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d, i) { return 0 })
        .x1(function(d, i) { return plan })
        .y0(function(d, i) { return y(actual); })
        .y1(function(d, i) { return y(variation); })
        .interpolate("basis");

        graph.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("d", area)
          .attr("fill", "#CCC");


});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/euGmMAvDpnVWKFNpMMQv?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning your area :

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d, i) { return 0 })
    .x1(function(d, i) { return plan })
    .y0(function(d, i) { return y(actual); })
    .y1(function(d, i) { return y(variation); })
    .interpolate("basis");
```

- x and x1 are returning static values, so it won't draw an area but just a line
- your both lines have same x axis so you just have to specify `.x()`
- y0 and y1 are also returnin static values

Here is a working version :

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
  .x(function(d, i) { return x(i) })
  .y0(function(d, i) { return y(data[i]); })
  .y1(function(d, i) {  return y(data1[i]); })
```

Also be careful, you have a `fill: none;` in your css file so you won't see anything.

Functional plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/xFNF3BQzd0IO5bauAiFU?p=preview

Comment: Yes, thanks. how to remove the `y` axis `stick` line ( y axis line)

Comment: you just have to remove this line `.call(yAxisLeft);`

Comment: my Y scale has 0 to 100 with 10 steps. how can i make this to 0 to 100 with 5 steps (like 0,20,40,60) instead of 10,20,30

Comment: You can do it "statically" : 
`yAxisLeft.ticks(5)`
You will have 5 ticks going from 0 to 100.
Or you can calculate it : 
`yAxisLeft.ticks(Math.round(y.domain()[1] / 20))` where `20` is your step side.